# C# upload file from Windows through WinSCP/SSH tunnel

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, ssh-tunnel, winscp-net

I use WinSCP desktop application on Windows server for a physical interface to upload files to a Linux server. I use SCP protocol, and in Advanced options I pass a SSH command `ssh username@ipaddress` on connection to security server to tunnel to the server where I want to upload files. This allows me to upload files directly from Windows through the Linux security server to the end point Linux file server.

Source Windows Server -> Security Linux Server -> Destination Linux Server

Using C# I can successfully upload or send a command using this [`Session.ExecuteCommand`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_executecommand) method/. However when I send the command `ssh username@ipaddress` my script hangs there. I believe that the session context changes there and some asynchronous C# magic needs to happen.

I can can successfully send asynchronous SSH commands using this: https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/Renci.SshNet/SshClient/CreateCommand/php-sshclient-createcommand-method-examples.html#0x12a75b3c713031851a6d9f2c47732ffcab6bad015f554fa89ef604d333290d4a-28,,45,

I need the C# equivalent to be able to emulate my Desktop WinSCP application where I pass the SSH command `ssh username@ipaddress` to freely upload from the source Windows server through a Linux Security Server to the remote Linux file server.

Can these examples be combined to create the C# code I need? A WinSCP session/SSH tunnel via Asynchronous Command. I am very familiar with the examples, please help!

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in WinSCP .NET assembly for "Shell" option in WinSCP GUI is:

```
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("Shell", "ssh username@ipaddress");
```

See [raw site settings](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawsettings).

WinSCP GUI can [generate a code template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#code) for you.

---

Though that might be an overkill, as WinSCP has SSH tunneling support built in, see the [Tunnel page of its Advanced site settings dialog](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_tunnel).

[image: Tunnel page]

---

C# equivalent for that is:

```
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("Tunnel", "on");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("TunnelHostName", "example.com");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("TunnelUserName", "john");
sessionOptions.AddRawSettings("TunnelPasswordPlain", "password");
```